# Sinch App-to-Phone not working

Tags: ios, sinch

I'm trying to implement app to phone calling from Sinch for IOS. I have successfully implemented app to app calling which means that the SDK is properly set up in my app. However the app to phone for some reason is not working:

In my MainViewController.m, I have the following:

```
- (id<SINClient>)client {
return [(JSQAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] client];
}
```

Then, in an alertView:

```
if ([self.client isStarted]) {

        id<SINCall> call = [self.client.callClient callPhoneNumber:@"+46000000000"]; //Testing the phone number as advised by Sinch!

        [self showCallController:call appToAppCall:NO];

    }
```

Which call the following method:

```
-(void)showCallController: (id<SINCall>)call appToAppCall: (BOOL)appToapp
 {

MMLCallingViewController *callView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CallingView"];

callView.call = call;
callView.callReceiverName = _theRecipient;
callView.calleeID = _theRecipientId;


if (!appToapp) {

    callView.typeOfCall = @"phone";
    callView.callStateLbl.text = @"Phone";
}

else {
    callView.typeOfCall = @"app";
}

[self presentViewController:callView animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Now each time, I tried to test the call - I have the following problem:

- The call view show, then stop suddenly with the below message showing in the console:

  ```
  [appDelegate client:logMessage:area:severity:timestamp:] [Line 590] virtual void rebrtc::SetSDPObserver::OnFailure(const std::string &)Failed to set remote answer sdp: Offer and answer descriptions m-lines are not matching. Rejecting answer.
  [appDelegate client:logMessage:area:severity:timestamp:] [Line 590] Failed to set remote answer sdp: Offer and answer descriptions m-lines are not matching. Rejecting answer.
  ```

My Sinch SDK version is: 3.7.1-0313526 - with Xcode 6.3 - IOS SDK 8.3

My Parse SDK version is 1.7.4

I have tried to look everywhere and read all the tutorials on Sinch! website about calling, and cannot find any clue for help.

Any help will be greatly appreciate. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi can you share your poejct on github, you can try and call my phone +15612600684

Comment: Hi! I have responded to your email. Unfortunately, My project isn't on github. I also tried to call your phone but that didn't change anything at all.

Comment: can you zipit and mail it to support?

Comment: Can you update to a later beta please. That should resolve the issue

Comment: Yeah! just update to the latest beta video and it just works fine. Great! One more thing, It keeps telling me that the call cannot be connected when I tried another number (like mine.. +336....) for instance even though, the sinch account is credited?